# Determine if file is PGP encrypted or not in Java

Tags: java, pgp

I have some files which are in encrypted format (PGP encryption) and some in raw format. Is there any way by which I can determine if my file is PGP encrypted or raw file so that I can call appropriate method for reading it in Java?

Comment: Can you try to decrypt the PGP encrypted file?

Comment: Yes, but that will give an issue if the file is raw , so my requirement is to determine first if the file is PGP encrypted or not.If Yes, willl decrypt and then read else just read

Answer (score 6):

On Linux `file` command performs this check

```
$ file testfile.txt 
testfile.txt: GPG encrypted data
```

It's implemented by looking at the first few bytes of the file:

- [`0xa600` means PGP](https://github.com/file/file/blob/deccd1a8e53463ba3c58304431fa7166396c2213/magic/Magdir/pgp#L52)
- [`0x8502` means GPG](https://github.com/file/file/blob/fd04f3df822e3934c557cf282615a61c04ca2324/magic/Magdir/gnu#L122)

If this magic number check is not reliable for your files you most likely need to attempt to decrypt the content and watch for errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can look if the file starts with

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
```

see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Aussehen_einer_verschl%C3%BCsselten_Nachricht (sorry not available in english wikipedia)

Comment: This is actually only the case of the file is "armored" when encrypting. If the file is not armored then it will just be a binary file which can be encoded in a thousand different ways. See here an exacter definition: "ASCII armor is a binary-to-textual encoding converter. ASCII armor is a feature of a type of encryption called pretty good privacy (PGP). ASCII armor involves encasing encrypted messaging in ASCII so that they can be sent in a standard messaging format such as email"